# ReactorNotRestartable error, how to use scrapy CrawlerProcess in for loop

Tags: python, loops, scrapy, reactor

I want use a sub-class to run my spider with different url and save info via loop. Here is my approach:

```
class Run_Spider_From_SubClass:

def __init__(self, url_list, *args, **kwargs):
    super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    self.url_list = url_list


def run_spider_in_loop(self):

    #here I start feeding urls, but more important I can save info for each 
    #crawling process, and then restart the process with another url along
    #loop.

    for url in self.url_list:    
        process = CrawlerProcess(get_project_settings())  # this drive the scrapy to use configuration in 'settings.py', all class must start from this
        process.crawl('MySpider', url)
        process.start()
        save_info  # any codes that save info from spider into target file
```

after this, I encounter reactor issue:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

File "G:/python/test/scrapy_test/test4.py", line 45, in <module>
Run_Spider_From_SubClass(url_list).run_spider_in_loop()

File "G:/python/test/scrapy_test/test4.py", line 34, in run_spider_in_loop
process.start()

File "C:\Users\super\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site- 
packages\scrapy\crawler.py", line 291, in start
reactor.run(installSignalHandlers=False)  # blocking call

File "C:\Users\super\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site- 
packages\twisted\internet\base.py", line 1266, in run
self.startRunning(installSignalHandlers=installSignalHandlers)

File "C:\Users\super\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site- 
packages\twisted\internet\base.py", line 1246, in startRunning
ReactorBase.startRunning(self)

File "C:\Users\super\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site- 
packages\twisted\internet\base.py", line 754, in startRunning
raise error.ReactorNotRestartable()
twisted.internet.error.ReactorNotRestartable
```

how to overcome this reactor error, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what exactly you plan on doing in `save_info`, but here is a minimal example of running the same spider multiple times sequentially. It is based on your class and the example in the [documentation](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/practices.html#running-multiple-spiders-in-the-same-process):

```
from twisted.internet import reactor, defer
from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerRunner
from scrapy.utils.log import configure_logging
from scrapy.utils.project import get_project_settings


class Run_Spider_From_SubClass:

    def __init__(self, url_list, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.url_list = url_list

        configure_logging()
        self.runner = CrawlerRunner(get_project_settings())

    @defer.inlineCallbacks
    def crawl(self):
        for url in self.url_list:
            yield self.runner.crawl('MySpider', url=url)
        reactor.stop()

    def run_spider_in_loop(self):
        self.crawl()
        reactor.run()


urls = ['http://something.com', 'http://another.com']
runner = Run_Spider_From_SubClass(urls)
runner.run_spider_in_loop()
```

Comment: Thanks reply, let me explain what I want to do with 'save_info': For each target url in url_list, I want to find sub-urls of this target url, and then extract info from all these urls, and save into one excel. So let say if I have 10 url in url_list, I will save 10 individual excel. Originally I can write code inside 'MySpider' to save info, but I have no idea if it will mess up the order in crawling process, because I found different urls and info process happen at the same time randomly. (observer from log when run spider). So by using 'loop', seem I have better control on feeding info

Comment: I'm not sure I follow the issue about the order, because generally it's not guaranteed anyway. But let me just confirm the output point: your goal is to write the results of each *top-level* URL into a separate file? So you don't want to process a single big file later? And there is no need for an individual spider to know about the results from the other spiders?

Comment: yes, you are right about what I am doing. And I just try your way, and then my code is working now, thank you very much!! My original code is little bit longer, because I am using openpyxl to store different info. I try my code many time for testing, and finally know my problem about running spider in loop. I should look at the 'common practice' more carefully, it did mention this way. Thank reminder and help!!!